# What is the mechanism that decides that setgroups() and initgroups() must be called with the superuser?

Tags: c, linux, privileges, access-control

From APUE

> ```
> #include <grp.h> /* on Linux */
> int setgroups(int ngroups, const gid_t grouplist[]);
> ```
>
> The `setgroups` function can be **called by the superuser** to set the supplementary group  ID  list  for  the  calling  process: grouplist contains  the  array  of  group  IDs,  and
>   ngroups speciﬁes the number of elements in the array. The value of ngroups cannot be larger than NGROUPS_MAX.
>
> ```
> #include <grp.h> /* on Linux and Solaris */
> int initgroups(const char *username, gid_t basegid);
> ```
>
> **One must  be  superuser**  to  call `initgroups()`, since  it  calls `setgroups()`.

What is the mechanism that decides that `setgroups()` and `initgroups()` must be called with the superuser?

By "mechanism", I mean something similar to or as a counterpart  to the following. in Linux, I  learned that we can determine accessibility of a process to a file, based on access control list (ACL):

- the effective user ID, effective group ID and supplementary group IDs of the process and
- the permission bits of the file.

Thanks.

Comment: For privileged operations, POSIX frequently uses the term 'appropriate privileges', which typically (and historically) means 'effective UID (EUID) of process is 0'. However, modern Linux also has capabilities, and there could be a capability which allows a different EUID to achieve the same result — and be POSIX compliant. (See, for example, POSIX [`setuid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setuid.html) for an example.) . POSIX doesn't define `initgroups()` or `setgroups()`, but similar rules would apply. Setting the groups list is inherently a privileged operation.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at the [actual code for setgroups](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/bdcf0a423ea1c40bbb40e7ee483b50fc8aa3d758/kernel/groups.c#L190). It starts like this:

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE2(setgroups, int, gidsetsize, gid_t __user *, grouplist)
{
    struct group_info *group_info;
    int retval;

    if (!may_setgroups())
        return -EPERM;

    // other stuff
}
```

And here is `may_setgroups`:

```
bool may_setgroups(void)
{
    struct user_namespace *user_ns = current_user_ns();

    return ns_capable(user_ns, CAP_SETGID) &&
        userns_may_setgroups(user_ns);
}
```

And here is `userns_may_setgroups`, if you aren't using user namespaces:

```
static inline bool userns_may_setgroups(const struct user_namespace *ns)
{
    return true;
}
```

So: `setgroups` will return an `EPERM` error *if you don't have the `CAP_SETGID` capability*.

Corollary: You can call `setgroups` if you have the `CAP_SETGID` capability.

Root has all capabilities automatically (so root can call `setgroups`), but you can also call it if you are not root and you have the `CAP_SETGID` capability.

Answer (score 2):

The wording in APUE is perhaps a bit imprecise; it's a tutorial guide for programmers, not a legal compendium. Any process can *call* `setgroups()` or `initgroups()`. But if the process does not have root privileges, the function will do nothing more than set `errno` to `EPERM` and return an error indication.

Obviously, the permissions test cannot be done with user privileges. The library function is just a thin wrapper around a syscall, and the tests are done inside the kernel.

For what it's worth, here is the first hit Google gave me when asked about the Linux syscall mechanism: http://www.linux.it/~rubini/docs/ksys/. But perhaps you have a better resource closer to hand.

Answer (score 2):

In Linux, if a process has the `CAP_SETGID` [capability](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html), the kernel will honor `setgid()`, `setegid()`, `setregid()`, `setresgid()`, and `setgroups()` calls (unless denied by a Linux Security Module like SELinux).

There are two main mechanisms how an unprivileged user may obtain a capability:

- Inheriting it from a privileged process. For normal users, extra capabilities may be granted by PAM modules at login.
- Via filesystem capabilities.

The filesystem capabilities are the more interesting, and useful for services/applications. They only work for binaries, not scripts, because the kernel updates the capabilities as part of the mechanism for executing binaries; scripts are interpreted by shells using a completely different, entirely userspace mechanism.

(The filesystem must support extended attributes. Some filesystems like ext2, ext3, and reiserfs, must be mounted with the `user_xattr` mount option to enable extended attributes. ext4, xfs, jfs, btrfs, and zfs all should support extended attributes using default mount options. Some Linux distributions like Debian and Ubuntu already rely on extended attributes and filesystem capabilities.)

Note: you can use the `getcap` and `lsattr` utilities to examine binaries filesystem capabilities and extended attributes. On my Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS system, the `/usr/bin/systemd-detect-virt` binary has both CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE and CAP_SYS_PTRACE capabilities permitted and effective.

Using filesystem capabilities is very easy in practice, but for safe operation, the security implications should be carefully considered first: it is a powerful tool, but you (developer, package manager, and/or system administrator) are responsible for making sure it is used correctly.

For example, if you are installing `/usr/bin/yourprog` that is trusted and requires the CAP_SETGID capability, all you need to do is set that capability permitted and effective for that binary. To do that, you run `setcap cap_setgid=pe /usr/bin/yourprog` with root privileges. (In a Debian .deb package install script, that is typically run in the post-install script.)